# Discord.py User Only Commands

Tags: python, discord.py, roles

I want to make a command that only me and my friend can use but all i can find is has role but i can't find anything to answer my question because everything that does will not work so is there any way to get it to work and if your wondering heres the script below

> ```
> @client.command(aliases=['rl'])
> @commands.has_role('3Peak-Bot-Dev-[RN/ou3PwQFA9uqbXSa6E+ClZJA3uTjK3n3Sl7g5hins=]')
> async def reload(ctx):
>     guild = ctx.guild
>     embed = discord.Embed(title = f'Reloading!', color = 0xff6300)
>     await ctx.send(embed=embed)
>     return await ctx.bot.logout()
> ```

Comment: Discord channel of discord.py is pretty active. You might want to consider asking the same question there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add code to check if the command was executed by you or your friend using the ID, for example:

```
@client.command(aliases=['rl'])
async def reload(ctx):
    yourID = 1234567890
    friendID = 1234567890
    if ctx.message.author.id == yourID or ctx.message.author.id == friendID:
        # Do something
    else:
        await ctx.send('You are not allowed to execute this command!')
```

If you don’t know how to get the User ID, [here’s a good guide.](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-)